# Merging two lists of dictionaries to create a third one in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let say I have the following:

```
list_a = [
    {u'username': u'firstuser', u'userid': u'1'},
    {u'username': u'seconduser', u'userid': u'2'},
    {u'username': u'thirduser', u'userid': u'3'},
]
```

and this one:

```
list_b = [
    {u'username': u'firstuser', u'userid': u'101'},
    {u'username': u'seconduser', u'userid': u'102'},
]
```

How can I obtain a third one like this:

```
list_result = [
    {u'username': u'firstuser', u'userid_one': u'1', u'userid_two': u'101'},
    {u'username': u'seconduser', u'userid_one': u'2', u'userid_two': u'102'},
    {u'username': u'thirduser', u'userid_one': u'3', u'userid_two': u''},
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing really relevant, I'm building a new list of dictionaries based on keys I need as they're more than the one mentioned and I only need a few of them and one which I need it the key value pair from the other list and I don't know how to get it. I tried to play a little with intersect but without success

Comment: It might help to build an intermediate dictionary which maps a username to a list of user ID's, then convert it back to a list of user profiles.

Comment: I've built a little intermediate function in order to extract both values, however my issue is that the lists are not ordered and also that they don't necessary contains all the username, one being a subset of the other, so I cannot just iterate over each items as the order is not identical neither the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a `dict` for each of the 2 input lists, like this:

```
dict_a = {
    e['username']: e['userid']
    for e in list_a}
dict_b = {
    e['username']: e['userid']
    for e in list_b}
```

---

Then build a new `dict` combining the data from both:

```
dict_result = {}

for username, userid in dict_a.items():
    if username not in dict_result:
        dict_result[username] = {}
    dict_result[username]['userid_one'] = userid
for username, userid in dict_b.items():
    if username not in dict_result:
        dict_result[username] = {}
    dict_result[username]['userid_two'] = userid
```

This can also be shortened to:

```
import collections
dict_result = collections.defaultdict(dict)

for label, d in [('one', dict_a), ('two', dict_b)]
    for username, userid in d.items():
        dict_result[username]['userid_{}'.format(label)] = userid
```

---

Finally, if you really need the end result as a list:

```
list_result = []

for username, d in dict_result.items():
    # 'd' already contains the other data, we just add the 'username'
    d['username'] = username

    list_result.append(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for having corrected the format of my question and for the answer which fully match my need. I was tired yesterday

Comment: My solution has linear time complexity (expressed as `O(n+m)`); for large lists it will be noticeable faster than using a doble for-loop (which will use quadratic time `O(n2)`). For small lists the difference will be meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following (before seeing both new answers):

```
final_list = []

for i in range(0, len(list_a)):
    d = {}
    userid_two = ''
    d['username'] = list_a[i]['username']
    for j in range(0, len(list_b)):
        if d['username'] == list_b[j]['username']:
            userid_two = list_b[j]['userid']
    d['userid_two'] = userid_two
    d['userid_one'] = list_a[i]['userid']
    final_list.append(d)
```

It looks pretty close to the recent answers but I don't know what's the best way of doing it

Comment: While this approach works, just note that this has cuadratic time complexity (`O(n2)`); it doesn't matter for small lists, but with a few hundert elements it will be noticeably slower than the answer you marked as accepted (thanks, by the way).

Comment: I fully agree with you and that was the point I wasn't happy with (time complexity) however, as both lists are pretty small (less than 200 for the first one and less than 100 for the second), I'll keep it as is

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result you want with the following way in a few lines of code:

```
list_a = [
    {u'username': u'firstuser', u'userid': u'1'},
    {u'username': u'seconduser', u'userid': u'2'},
    {u'username': u'thirduser', u'userid': u'3'},
]

list_b = [
    {u'username': u'firstuser', u'userid': u'101'},
    {u'username': u'seconduser', u'userid': u'102'},
]

# Get all users from both lists.
users = set(elem['username'] for elem in list_a + list_b)
# Get all ids for every user from the above list we created.
userids = [{user:[elem['userid'] for elem in list_a + list_b if elem['username']==user]} for user in users]
# Add a padding of a maximum of two elements in order to fill any missing values with ''.
userids = [{key: ids + [''] * (2-len(ids))} for user in userids for key , ids in user.items()]
# Create final list.
list_c = [{'username':key, 'userid_one':values[0], 'userid_two':values[1]} for elem in userids for key, values in elem.items()]
print(list_c)
```

Final result:

```
[{'username': 'seconduser', 'userid_one': '2', 'userid_two': '102'}, {'username': 'thirduser', 'userid_one': '3', 'userid_two': ''}, {'username': 'firstuser', 'userid_one': '1', 'userid_two': '101'}]
```